# Find and count nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count, find

I have mongodb collection with data e.g.

```
{"test": "test1"} 
{"test": "test2"}
{"test": "test3"}
```

From the database level it searches without a problem:

```
db.collection.find({test: "test1"}).count();
```

Gets the result: 13

However, from the nodejs level when I have:

```
    var counter = db.collection('collection').find({test: "test1"}).count();
    counter.forEach (function (doc, err) {
         assert.equal (null, err);
         resultArray.push (doc);
     }, function () {
         client.close ();
         console.log ("resultArray", resultArray);
     });
```

Result: forEach is not a function

What should I use so that I can then display this value in EJS

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `db.collection.find({test: "test1"}).count()` returns a number, as you see you're getting `13`, Since it's a number you can't do `.forEach` on it. As `forEach` will only work on arrays, which is meant to iterate over each element in an array to execute some operation.

**Ex:-** `[1,2,3].forEach(i => console.log(i))` will log `1`,`2`,`3`. But if you pass anything other than an array to `.forEach` will throw an error exactly what you're getting.

Also you can change your query & code as well, So you can try these :

```
db.collection('collection').count({ test: "test1" }, (err, counter) => {
    if (err) {/** return from here */ }
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('Total no.of docs matched ::', counter)
    resultArray.push(counter); // What is this resultArray, anyway it has to be an array ?
}, function () {
    client.close();
    console.log("resultArray", resultArray);
});
```

Just in case of you need all docs & also their count, then just use `.find()` :

```
db.collection('collection').find({ test: "test1" }).toArray((err, resp) => {
    if (err) {/** return from here */ }
    assert.equal(null, err);
    /** Here resp will be an array of objects or [] */
    if (resp.length) {
        resultArray.concat(resp)
        console.log('Total no.of docs matched ::', resp.length)
    }
    console.log('No docs found for given filter');
}, function () {
    client.close();
    console.log("resultArray", resultArray);
});
```

Comment: This is practically what I mean.
Thank you for your answer in my topic.
But I still have to display it in res.render (to make it available for EJS).
Now resultArray is not available to me after db.collection query.
After function() { client.close(); I dont have console.log resultArray
I have some other database queries in the router and I write everything in res.render at the very end.
Can you help me ?

Comment: @Mr.Pat : what do you mean by resultArray not available? And what else do you need?

Comment: I edited my post for code, customer_count: resultArray1 is not visible in /list

Comment: @Mr.Pat : Your code has a lot of issues !! What exactly you need ? `database.collection('collection').aggregate([{ $count: "employee_name" }])` -> is not needed & `employee_count_cursor.forEach` -> won't work. Also those two DB calls has to be in parallel !! Can you please revert this edit & keep the post original, Let's close this question without any added clutter which makes question looks clean in future- Please raise a new question with all needed things :-)

Answer (score 0):

It just seems like your not waiting for the promise to resolve, `find` returns a cursor and does not have a `forEach` function.

Change your line into this should solve the issue:

```
var counter = await db.collection('collection').find({test: "test1"});
```

Comment: I get the result:
await is only valid in async function  // I forgot to add .count at the end also